# Warning: Received NaN for the `value` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string. input on multipart form

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multipartform-data, parseint

I have created a multipart form in React and I think my text and file fields are passing the data correctly to my console however the int values seem to be throwing errors. I know I should be using parseInt to parse these as numeric values but I am not sure if I am doing this correctly.

There is a populate dropdown menu with Redux data passed into it which has it displaying correctly however whatever way I am setting the state seems to be throwing the NaN error in my console**. I know that e.target.value will always convert to string so how would I go about parsing this to an INT?**

```
// state for the current field value
    const [spot, setSpot] = useState({
        diveLocation: ``,
        diveRegionID: parseInt(``),
        diveTypeID: parseInt(``),
        diveSpotDescription: ``,
        diveSpotPhotos: ``,
        error: ``
    });

.....
const handleChange = (property) => (e) => {
        setSpot({
            // override the changed property and keep the rest
            ...spot,
            [property]: e.target.value,
        });
    }

    const handleChangeInt = (property) => (e) => {
        setSpot({
            // override the changed property and keep the rest
            ...spot,
            [property]: e.target.valueAsNumber,
        });
    }
```

```
<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                        <PopulateDropdown
                            dataList={diveTypeList}
                            titleProperty={"diveType"} // option label property
                            valueProperty={"diveTypeID"} // option value property
                            name="diveType"
                            placeholder="Dive Type"
                            label="Select Dive Type"
                            value={spot.diveTypeID}
                            onChange={handleChange("diveTypeID")}/>
                    </FormControl>
```

error message

[image]

[image]

**Update**

I have added in a separate "handleChangeInt" to convert the e.targetValue to a number however now my dropdown fields won't let my select a field and go blank whenever I choose an option.

```
<PopulateDropdown
    dataList={diveTypeList}
    titleProperty={"diveType"} // option label property
    valueProperty={"diveTypeID"} // option value property
    name="diveType"
    placeholder="Dive Type"
    label="Select Dive Type"
    value={spot.diveTypeID}
    **onChange={handleChangeInt("diveTypeID")}/>**
```

The first two fields below won't hold a value when I click on a select option now that I have entered an extra handleChange to parse my INTs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your state with the empty string `""` or a value matching with one of the options provided to select component.

So, initialize with empty string:

```
const [spot, setSpot] = useState({
  diveLocation: "",
  diveRegionID: "", // here
  diveTypeID: "", // and, here
  diveSpotDescription: "",
  diveSpotPhotos: "",
  error: ""
});
```

You can also use two [back ticks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to create empty string.

Comment: If the two id INT fields still aren't populating does this mean I need one combined method for the e.target.values? When I select rhe option it is still appearing blank. I have tried both "" and ``.

Comment: I would better understand and help you if you can create a sandbox. You can start by forking this https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-2qg4g?file=/demo.tsx It has a sample Select Material UI dropdown. It is in TypeScript but that's not important, you can ignore the TS.

Comment: This is the front-end code I have at the minute. https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-fire-5llfg?file=/src/populateDropdown.js Do you need the backend?

Comment: The fields were populating before when i just had the one handleChange but the INT's weren't being parsed as integers.

Comment: Actually, codesandbox isn't a way to share code, but it is about creating a demo (with minimal code) that runs and reproduces the error / issue. But I can manage.  Which file / which component line should I look at?

Comment: Apologies, It's the form component then I have the actiion for the form submission then the dropdown menu which the two ID fields aren't populating.

Comment: Yes that would be great if you could. :)